# Move container above footer

Tags: html, css

I am currently new to the community, and would love some help with a HTML site I am creating for a friend of mine. 
Basicly I man creating a simple website, but I have some issues with the text not going above the footer. I check the code and tried to figure out how to solve this, but I was unable to do so. 
My question is: could someone help me putting the text above the footer? 
Please let me know !

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    background-color: #111;
}
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;

}
h2 {
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.x {
    color: #ef3937; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.container {
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%;
}
/*-------------------------------HEADER--------------------------------*/
.headercontainer {
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    top:0px; 
    background-color: #111;
}
.header {
    width: 95%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
.headerleft {}
.headercenter {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    color:#f2f2f2;
}
.logo {
    max-width: 200px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.headerright {}
/*-----------------------------END HEADER------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------CONTENT--------------------------------*/
.contentcontainer {
    Position: absolute; 
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    padding-top: 0%; 
    background-color:#111;
}
.content {
    width: 75%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
.contenleft {}
.contentcenter {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.contentright {}
/*-----------------------------END CONTENT-----------------------------*/


/*-------------------------------FOOTER--------------------------------*/
.clearfooter {}

.footercontainer { 
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #111; 
    bottom: 20;
}
.footer {
    width: 75%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
.footerleft {}
.footercenter {
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 8px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-family: 'Economica'; 
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.footerright {}
/*-----------------------------END FOOTER------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------ALGEMEEN-------------------------------*/
a {text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}
a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Champagne & Limousines'), url('Champagne & Limousines.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Italic';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Champagne & Limousines Italic'), url('Champagne & Limousines Italic.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Bold';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Champagne & Limousines Bold'), url('Champagne & Limousines Bold.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic'), url('Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><![endif]-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">-->
 <title>Froluv</title>

 <meta name="Froluv." content="PSD to HTML5+CSS3 conversion.">
 <meta name="Froluv" content="PSD, HTML5, CSS3">
 <meta name="author" content="Vivaco">

    
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleCSS.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="headercontainer">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="headerleft">
            </div>
            
            <div class="headercenter">
                <div class="logocontainer"> 
                    <img src="" class="logo"> <!--insert logo here-->
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="headerright">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------END HEADER----------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------CONTENT----------------------------------------------------------------------->  
    <div class="contentcontainer">
        <div class="content">   
            <div class="contentleft">
            </div>
            
            <div class="contentcenter">
                <h1 style="font-family:'Champagne &amp; Limousines';font-weight:normal;font-size:42px">“Wij organiseren events, kom je <u><b><a href="">dansen</a></b></u>?”</h1> 
                <!--Insert ticket link here-->
            </div>            
                
            
            <div class="contentright">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------END CONTENT-------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------FOOTER------------------------------------------------------------------------->


            
    <div class="footercontainer">        
            <div class="footer">
                    
                <div class="footerleft">
                </div>
                    
                <div class="footercenter">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="">FACEBOOK</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">INSTAGRAM</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">SPOTIFY</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">TICKETS</a>
                         
                    <span class="x">x</span>  <span class="x">x</span>  <span class="x">x</span> PRIVACY POLICY <span class="x">x</span> FAQ <span class="x">x</span> JOBS
                    </h2>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="footerright">
                </div>
                
        </div>
    </div>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------END FOOTER----------------------------------------------------------------------->
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Short answer is don't use `position: absolute;` (for any of the elements you have so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using absolute positioning until you have a better understanding of when and where to use it and what problems it helps to solve.

By undoing the absolute positioning you have applied, the content will be in the correct order. Though, may likely need further refinement to fit your needs.

In my example below, I have used `flexbox` to push the footer to the bottom of the page. You'll also notice I've removed a lot of properties that are not necessary, i.e. `width: 100%` for a `<div>` (it does this by default).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #111;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Champagne &amp; Limousines';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42px;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.x {
  color: #ef3937;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container {}


/*-------------------------------HEADER--------------------------------*/

.headercontainer {}

.header {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.headerleft {}

.headercenter {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.headerright {}


/*-----------------------------END HEADER------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------CONTENT--------------------------------*/

.contentcontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #111;
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.contenleft {}

.contentcenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.contentright {}


/*-----------------------------END CONTENT-----------------------------*/


/*-------------------------------FOOTER--------------------------------*/

.clearfooter {}

.footercontainer {}

.footer {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.footerleft {}

.footercenter {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Economica';
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.footerright {}


/*-----------------------------END FOOTER------------------------------*/


/*------------------------------ALGEMEEN-------------------------------*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Champagne & Limousines'), url('Champagne & Limousines.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Champagne & Limousines Italic'), url('Champagne & Limousines Italic.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Champagne & Limousines Bold'), url('Champagne & Limousines Bold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic'), url('Champagne & Limousines Bold Italic.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="headercontainer">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerleft">
    </div>

    <div class="headercenter">
      <div class="logocontainer">
        <img src="" class="logo">
        <!-- insert logo here -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="headerright">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="contentcontainer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentleft">
    </div>

    <div class="contentcenter">
      <h1>“Wij organiseren events, kom je <u><b><a href="">dansen</a></b></u>?”</h1>
      <!--Insert ticket link here-->
    </div>


    <div class="contentright">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END CONTENT -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="footercontainer">
  <div class="footer">

    <div class="footerleft">
    </div>

    <div class="footercenter">
      <h2>
        <a href="">FACEBOOK</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">INSTAGRAM</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">SPOTIFY</a> <span class="x">x</span> <a href="">TICKETS</a>

        <span class="x">x</span> <span class="x">x</span> <span class="x">x</span> PRIVACY POLICY <span class="x">x</span> FAQ <span class="x">x</span> JOBS
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="footerright">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As advised minutes ago, just remove the position:absolute from .contentcontainer and it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/ilkovs/yqdg62fe/3/

```
.contentcontainer {
height: auto; 
width: 100%; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
padding-top: 0%; 
background-color:#111;
```

}

instead of :

```
.contentcontainer {
Position: absolute; 
height: auto; 
width: 100%; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
padding-top: 0%; 
background-color:#111;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how to use `position:absolute`, if you use `absolute` you are taking the `<Div>` out of the flow of the page, so I think you should use `relative` positioning instead of `absolute`.

Then again, if you are going to use `absolute`, you need to specify one of these four(4) properties which are:
`top, bottom, left, right`, these four properties help you to move the `<div>` around the page anyhow you like and can help you shift your text up.

Last thing all the different types of positions all use the same four properties I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Separate your header and footer. 1. div for header, 2. another div for content 3. footer. in your footer css, add margin-bottom:0; and  margin-top: 200px; That is a quick fix, but after separating the three, you can play around the CSS to fit your design need

[image: Header on top.]